# Method to erase textboxes by clicking a button

Tags: winforms, forms, button, methods, textbox

I am working on a Windows Forms Application project (it is an assignment). And [this](http://postimg.org/image/ywkeyuc5f) is how the form should look like.

I need to write a method that when clicking on the 'Add' button textboxes are erased, so the new value which user adds could be accepted.

Comment: Did you tried anything?

Comment: Yes, but since I am a beginner, it just doesn't work, I don't know what kind of method I should use. :/

Comment: Why don't you post your code? Someone will point you the error and it surely will improve your question, because, as is, it belongs to the 'write my code please' kind

Answer (score 1):

A *very simple* example of what you are asking for is:

```
private void ClearText()
{
   Control[] aryControls = { txtBirthday, txtFirstName, txtLastName, txtID };

   foreach (Control ctrl in aryControls)
   {
      ctrl.Text = "";
   }
}
```

Comment: THANK YOU SO SOO MUCH! Will try with this. Thanks again!